# Extract rows from Multi-index dataframe where child level matches numbers on Numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multi-index

From the following Multi-index dataframe:

```
        a   b   c
0   0   0   42  65
    1   6   0   340
    2   5   71  800
    3   2   51  409
    4   0   23  279
    5   8   38  549
1   0   1   23  252
    1   9   13  977
    2   1   19  943
2   0   2   23  295
    1   3   39  458
    2   1   62  308
    3   0   95  954
    4   9   78  535
3   0   4   67  849
    1   3   46  761
    2   7   49  485
    3   0   44  638
```

How can I extract the rows from the dataframe that matches the numbers on a Numpy array? For instance, if my array is:

```
a = np.array([2, 2, 4, 3])
```

The result should be a dataframe like:

```
    a   b   c
0   5   71  800
1   1   19  943
2   9   78  535
3   0   44  638
```

I have tried the following:

```
i,j = df.index.levels
ix = a
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy()[ix])
```

but that's giving me the wrong result. The dataframe I'm currently getting is:

```
    a   b   c
0   5   71  800
1   5   71  800
2   0   23  279
3   2   51  409
```

It's actually reading the index from df1 instead of df.

Comment: What is the logic? Should each number match the first level? Or should repeats be taken in order? What should be the result for `a = np.array([2, 5, 0, 2])`

Comment: Each number item on the array correspond to the first level. The integer corresponds to the second level. For example, first item on the array is first level 0 and second level 2. Second item in the array is first level 1 and second level 2 etc.

Comment: Thanks @mozway. It works but the output is not quite what I specified on my question. Apologies, but I'm not an expert and I'm wondering how can I get the result as specified in my question i.e. without the unlabelled second column? The results for columns a, b and c are correct.

Comment: simply add `.droplevel(1)` to drop the second index level (`df.loc[zip(b,a)].droplevel(1)` or `df.reindex(zip(b,a)).droplevel(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use one number for each level you could use direct slicing:

```
a = np.array([2, 2, 4, 3])
b = df.index.get_level_values(0).unique().to_numpy() # to_numpy() is optional
# b = array([0, 1, 2, 3])

df.loc[zip(b,a)]
```

output:

```
     a   b    c
0 2  5  71  800
1 2  1  19  943
2 4  9  78  535
3 3  0  44  638
```

If you want to handle potentially incorrect data, use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
a = np.array([2, 5, 0, 2])
# b = df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()

df.reindex(zip(b,a))
```

output:

```
       a     b      c
0 2  5.0  71.0  800.0
1 5  NaN   NaN    NaN
2 0  2.0  23.0  295.0
3 2  7.0  49.0  485.0
```